# Uploading ALAsset to Dropbox

Tags: upload, nsurl, dropbox, alasset

I'm using the Dropbox API for the iPhone to upload a photo from the camera roll to a Dropbox account.

However, to accomplish this I seem to have to save the full resolution image of the ALAsset to a file and then upload that file to Dropbox.

I'm thinking there must be an easier way. But the Dropbox API wants a path to the original file and not a NSURL to the original file.

The [asset.defaultRepresentation.url absoluteString] yields "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=3CFC9CD9-22AF-445B-AC39-E574DBAE156C&ext=JPG" which the Dropbox API is not happy to use.

and

[asset.defaultRepresentation.url path] yields "/asset.JPG"

Can I use the NSURL from the ALAsset?
Is there a better approach than saving the image to a file first?

Thanks,
Brian.